# Writing a function to specify which group/variable combination to send to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a data frame similar to `df`:

```r
ID = c(letters[1:10])
num = c(1000,1200,1234,980,1300,1400,1251,1111,1354,1256)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(ID, num), num = sequence(num))
df[paste0('Var', seq_along(ID))] <- rnorm(length(ID) * sum(num))
df$Location = rep(c("alpha", "beta"), each = 6043)
```

There are 10 variables that were measured on several individuals (each denoted by a unique `ID`). The individuals (`ID`s) are nested within `Location`, of which there are 2 in this example. So `ID`s a:e belong to `Location` alpha, and `ID`s f:j belong to `Location` beta
I have been making the plots I want by creating a new object that holds the observations for each unique `Location`. For each variable (`Var1:Var10`), I plot all members of that `Location` on the same graph like this:

```r
#example plot for alpha
alpha <- df%>%
  filter(Location == "alpha")
ggplot(df, aes(x=num, y=Var1))+
  labs(x= "num(distance)",y="Variable")+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID))
```

My real data set has a lot of variable/ID combinations, so I am trying to write a function that I can just provide the `Location` and `Var` that I want to use to produce the same kind of plot
I have tried several variants of this, but am having trouble getting anything to work:

```r
TSplot <- function(Location, Variable){
  ggplot(df, aes(x = num, y = Variable))+
      labs(x= "num(distance)", y=paste(Variable))+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID))
}

TSplot(alpha, Var1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question  - thanks for providing a useful example set.  You did not post an error message, but I'm guessing if you sent `TSplot(df, Location, Variable)`, you're getting an error `"Error in paste(Variable) : object 'variable' not found"`.

This is because `ggplot` is expecting you to send a "named object", whereas you're sending the name.

As an example, say you let `x` be this vector:

```
x <- c('red', 'blue')
```

You can recall that vector (a "named object") if you just type the name, the console returns the object itself (the vector):

```
> x
[1] "red"  "blue"  # I asked for the object called "x", I got the object itself
```

But if you send to the console `"x"` (just the name), you get back `"x"`, not the object.

```
> "x"
"x"    # thanks, console.  That's what I typed.  Note this is not the object called "x"
```

Is it possible to send "the name", or in this case, just "x", and get back the object?  Yes!  For that, you use the function `get()`, [which returns the value of a named object](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/get):

```
> get("x")   # asking for the object named "x"
[1] "red"  "blue"   # I get the object, not the name
```

So now it should be obvious how you change your function to work.  You can send to a function the name of an object:  `function(df)`, for example, would be sending "your entire dataframe object" to the function.  But it doesn't work to send the name of a component within that named object.  You can send the column name as `df$column.name`, but it would not work to send `function(column.name)`, because if you type `column.name` into the console, you don't get `df$column.name`.

You can make your function work by changing so that you incorporate `get()` where you need to "get" the object using a reference name only, so something like this should work:

```
Tsplot <- function(df, Variable){
    ggplot(df, aes(x = num, y = get(Variable)))+
        labs(x= "num(distance)", y=paste(Variable))+
        geom_line(aes(color = ID))
}
```

You should be able to send `Tsplot(df, 'Var1')` and it will work.  If you send `Tsplot(df, Var1)` it will not work.

Alternatively, if you just want to send a character string to `aes()`, you can just use `aes_string()` instead.  If you are combining calls using characters and using names of objects, it's probably better to use `aes()` in conjunction with `get()` though.  In other words, `aes(x=name, y=get(character))` does it in one `aes()` call, but with `aes_string()` you'd have to use two: `aes(x=name)`, `aes_string(y=character)`.

*Oh, and I guess that is an excerpt of your* complete function, since the example you posted there didn't include "Location".  Same thing applies there though.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different ways to approach this. I tried to build off of what you had provided.

One way is to provide the data frame, and in addition the location and variable as strings for function arguments.

If you use strings in the aesthetic for `ggplot`, you can use `aes_string`.

```
library(tidyverse)

TSplot <- function(df_input, location, variable) {
  df_input %>%
    filter(Location == location) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = "num", y = variable)) +
      labs(x = "num (distance)", y = variable) +
      geom_line(aes(color = ID))
}

TSplot(df_input = df, location = "alpha", variable = "Var1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood well the structure of yout data but did you tried :

```
TSplot <- function(df_input ,Location, Variable){
df=df_input  
ggplot(df, aes(x=num, y=Var1))+
  labs(x= "num(distance)",y="Variable")+
  geom_line(aes(color = ID))

}


newdata <- df[ which(df$Location=="alpha"), ]  # we select rows with criterion = "alpha"

TSplot(newdata,Location, Variable) # we plot the wanted data
```

Comment: I made some changes to clarify the structure of my data